# Get the value of another field in package.json file (npm)

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I have the following `package.json` file:

```
{
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:live": "tsc && node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

How can I get the value of the `main` field, then put it into the command `node ./dist/index.js`, something like this (just a example, I know this `$` is for ENV variables):

```
{
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:live": "tsc && node $main"
  },
  ...
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

All package.json fields are available as variables by prefixing them with `$npm_package_`. In your example, you can use this:

```
{
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:live": "tsc && node $npm_package_main"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this `$npm_package_` capability appears to have been removed from npm with version 7.  I found out by reading <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2609>.